# What is the strategy on implementing a jwt auto login?

Tags: javascript, next.js, jwt, authorization, js-cookie

I'm new to jwt authorisation. Where I come from is just user and password authorisation without jwt. Now, that I learned the basics of jwt, I want to use is and here is my question:

In my login component, I collect email and password and of correct, I send a signed JWT to the user. I store that token with `js-cookie`. (I hope until here are no issues).

Now in my `_app.js` (I'm using nextjs) I think, if there is a component that requires data, I just built the app, as there was no login. Only thing I'd change, if the data fetch does not succeed, I'd send the user to the login screen.
With that, the user would be auto logged in, as long he has the cookie and neither the cookie, nor the token, do expire.

Or is there a better approach?

Edit after reading the comments:
In the mean time I added Auth0 login to my app. I disabled all sign ups and created the user in the Auth0 database. The downside for me is, that the setup of the app now takes longer, as I need to configure another third-party. But fair enough, when this increases the security.

But now my questions changes: Can I stop using JWT now, because I can trust the user, that is logged in? I'd say no, because the API is an open API without JWT protection, so anyhow my question did not really change?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not try to issue your own tokens, instead use a openid-connect certified token service (like [KeyCloak](https://www.keycloak.org/), AzureAd, [Auth0](https://auth0.com/), [Ping](https://ping.com/) , [IdentityServer](https://duendesoftware.com/)...)

Secondly you should try to avoid storing tokens in a cookie or even in the browser. A video discussing the security issue is the one below that I can highly recommend:

[alert‘OAuth 2 0’; // The impact of XSS on OAuth 2 0 in SPAs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw&ab_channel=PhilippeDeRyck)

Comment: Thank you, I'll check that out. Is this even recommended, when I have only one user and no registration and using nextJS with server-side rendering?

Comment: What I want to do is: I have an admin panel for a webpage with one admin account. You should be able to see the content only if you are logged in. So usually I'd add that user to a mysql database and than make a default email and password login form, but sending the JWT

Comment: The benefit now with Auth0 is that you do not need to deal with users or passwords and now you can login to your site. Under the hood there are JWT tokens exchanged (id-token). now, if you need access token? perhaps not if the API is public

Comment: You mean private? Yes Login is very easy with auth0, but if the logged in user now makes `fetch("https://api.myserver.com/all_users_with_sensitive_data")` - how can I protect that from the outside?

Comment: Well it depends on how you are integrating with Auth0, but you can use JWT access tokens or session cookie to secure the access the API if the API is on the same domain as the application. There are quite a few "it depends" here, so hard to exactly say what you should do